# code for the sum of a Fibonacci sequence doesnt give the correct sum

Tags: python

I wrote this code to calculate the sum of any n that I input for the Fibonacci sequence.

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    elif n==2:
        return 2
    else:
        num = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        return num 
    return sum(num)

fib(7)
```

This produces an output of 21 when it's supposed to produce an outcome of 20? It always seems to output a sum of one more than the actual sum

Comment: Note that `fib(2)` should also be equal to `fib(0) + fib(1)`, which is not the case with your definition.

Comment: Your base cases are wrong. The sequence starts `0, 1, 1, 2, ...`, not `0, 1, 2, ...`.

Comment: Also, your last `return` will (luckily, as it would raise an error) never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

It's because for `n=2` the result is `f(0)+f(1)= 0+1 =1` and not `2` so `return 1` so you can remove that condition, also the `sum` code is useless and it not reachable, so it becomes :

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

# can be shorten with python if/else inline syntax
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

You can find others implementations here : [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence#answers)

---

TO get the sum of fibo values, you may store the values, to not count them a lots of time, solution : `array`. And if you manage to use it several time, get the array out of the function, here is an example of how to use it to be performant

```
fibonacci_numbers = [0, 1]
def fibo_setup(max_value=10):
    """Compute the values until a limit, and store in a list"""
    for i in range(len(fibonacci_numbers), max_value):
        fibonacci_numbers.append(fibonacci_numbers[i - 1] + fibonacci_numbers[i - 2])

def fibo(n):
    """Retrieve a fibo value using the array, compute if not present"""
    if len(fibonacci_numbers) < n:
        fibo_setup(n + 1)
    return fibonacci_numbers[n]

def fibo_sum(n):
    """Get the sum of fibo values, and before it checks that the array is filled"""
    fibo_setup(n)
    return sum(fibonacci_numbers[:n])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fibo_setup(10)
    print(fibo(12))
    print(fibo_sum(15))
```

Comment: this works out the fibonacci sequence at n=7 but not the sum of 1-7

Comment: @user12386893 I've edit at the bottom with a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

While it's tempting to write a neat short recursive function, it's usually is a bad idea, specially, when you need to access all the values, e.g. in this case

```
fib(0) + fib(1) + ... + fib(n)
```

Instead, employ an array:

```
def fib_sum(n):
    # edge cases
    if n==0: return 0
    if n<=2: return n-1

    # store first n fibonacci numbers
    fib = [0] * n

    # initialization
    fib[1] = 1

    for i in range(2,n):
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]

    return sum(fib)

fib_sum(7)
# 20
```

Comment: what does this part of the code do exactly? fibo = [0] * n
how does it store the Fibonacci numbers? or is this creating the array to then later store the Fibonacci number?

Comment: Yes. That’s an array to store the first n Fibonacci numbers.